# How to set an empty or not empty entry for a switch case statement?

Tags: groovy, switch-statement

I'd like to know to set an entry to validate if a String is empty or not empty in a switch-case statement. Let me show you:

```
String str = 'value'
switch(str){
    case str == '':
        println('Entered an empty value')
        break
    case str != '':
        println('Entered value '+str)
        break
    case 'CoDe':
        println('Entered special code '+str)
        break
    default:
        println('Incorrect entry')
        break
}
```

I know how to set an entry with a value (case 3) but I don't know how to set a entry with an empty or not empty string value.

Any help?

Comment: That's what `if`s are for.

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense even if it was valid. When would the `'CoDe'` or `default` cases be hit if you already have a case for non-empty?

Comment: May I assume that the absence of semicolons and the use of single quotes for Strings are features of groovy?  It's a bit confusing that this is tagged with two different languages.  I'm a Java specialist, which makes this hard for me to answer if it's a groovy question.

Comment: Hi @shmosel I now this can be solved with an IF statement, and I also know that one of the cases would invalidate other cases, this was just a dummy code. I just wanted to see how to set a case with an empty string and other case with a non empty string. I searched on google but I couldn't find an example. In my code I have more conditions so switch-case was necessary. I appreciate the comments

Comment: Hi @DawoodibnKareem correct, with Groovy there is no need for semi-colon. I tagged the two languages because  I use Katalon for automation testing and it's default language is groovy but it also accepts Java. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a smell, as `str != ''` would block all further `case`s.

I would re-organize it and use straight-forward basic Groovy switch-statement:

```
String str = 'value'
switch(str){
    case 'CoDe':
        println "Entered special code $str"
        break
    case '':
        println 'Entered an empty value'
        break
    case { str != '' && str != null }:
        println "Entered value $str"
        break
    default:
        println 'Incorrect entry'
}
```

prints

```
Entered value value
```

Comment: Hi, This is was I was looking for. I forgot to mention this was a dummy code. But I couldn't find examples on google for this: `case '':` and this `case { str != '' && str != null }:`

Answer (score 1):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73535623/how-to-set-an-empty-or-not-empty-entry-for-a-switch-case-statement#comment129856727_73535623), what you need in Java is a series of `if` tests.

In the `String` class, you can test either:

- The string has no characters at all ([`isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()))
- The string has no characters OR has only [whitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(int)) characters ([`isBlank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()))

```java
if ( str.isEmpty() ) { System.out.println( "ERROR - String has no characters." ); }
else if ( str.isBlank() ) { System.out.println( "ERROR - String has only whitespace." ); }
else if ( str.equals( "CoDe" ) ) { System.out.println( "Code received." ); }
else { System.out.println( "ERROR - Incorrect entry." ); }
```

See that [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/LPZJvr).

Before that code block, I would add a null-check.

```
Objects.requireNonNull( str ); // Throw exception if null.
```

I find the `if - else if - else` construct in Java to be awkward in terms of readability. The `switch` syntax is much better at making obvious that a series of possibilities is being tested, mutually-exclusive, with a single result.

I do wish Java offered a cascading test for a series of boolean expressions. I have used such a feature in another language. There I found the cascading-boolean-tests to be quite practical for handling a series of business rules. But, alas, no such feature in Java. If only Brian Goetz were taking my calls.

---

I do not know Groovy. Perhaps Groovy provides another facility.

Comment: "I do wish Java offered a cascading test for a series of boolean expressions." - What is it that you mean by a cascading test?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown A series of boolean expressions, one evaluated after another, until one returns `true`.

Comment: "A series of boolean expressions, one evaluated after another, until one returns" - Java support that with something like `x > 5 || y > 11 || z == 4`.  `||` should short circuit as soon as one is `true`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown But each boolean expression leads to different code being executed. Imagine a Java `switch` style statement where each `case` is a boolean expression. This would behave like a `if - else if - else` series, but with more obvious formatting in the code editor, and without the nonsense of `break` fall-through. Such a simple idea, but handy in the real-world for dealing with complicated wonky business rules, like « if this user is a manager but not an executive », else « if this user is not in management but the subject matter is marked ‘priority’ » …

Comment: "But each boolean expression leads to different code being executed" - I got it now.  I misunderstand "A series of boolean expressions, one evaluated after another, until one returns true".  Makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I forgot to mention this was a dummy example. They are useful

Answer (score 1):

I tested it, and I think I have the answer for you.

```
    switch(str) {
        case "": // empty
            println("Entered an empty value")
            break
        case "CoDe": // str == CoDe
            println("Entered special code "+str)
            break
        default: // String not empty and not "CoDe"
            println("Not empty")
            break
    }
```

It works because you have `case ""` which is the empty string. Meaning that **everithing else** is not empty. everything else is the **default:**

If you are not convinced, I'll give you a different example with the same meaning.

```
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
       // do something
    } else if (!str.isEmpty()) { // <- this if is redundant
       // do something else
    }
```

You don't need the second if, because, you enter the else branch only if str is not empty! I appleid the same logic to the case. And it works because `case "":`  in Java is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I forgot to mention this was a dummy example. They are useful